# Prerequisites for android platform development

Tags: android, android-source

What are the prerequisites for android platform development ?
Is it linux kernel , linux administration or just familiarity of linux system ?

Comment: Prerequisites from what point? And for what kind of platform development? There are tons of different components to AOSP from kernel to system apps to regular apps...

Comment: Have you gone through this? - http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

Comment: i want to contribute to android source code . so what should i learn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment being about how you want to contribute to AOSP, I would take a look at the [Contributing to AOSP](https://source.android.com/source/contributing.html) page.

All your contributions go through [gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) so reading up about that would also be useful.

Bugs and issues for AOSP can range in a variety of languages and forms, and they can use anyone with proficiency with c, java, and make files to name a few. Any knowledge on those subjects can be helpful.

You should also look into the [Style Guidelines](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) for contributing to AOSP or most of your patches will be rejected, they are very strict.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Learn Basic Object Oriented Programming, Java, other then this you should be familiar with Eclipse or ADT plugin as the Integrated Development Environment ( IDE) to work  on Android Platform.
Linux is not required for New learners (Beginner).

Comment: This completely depends on what kind of development you want to do on the platform. Even for apps, you don't need to develop with eclipse, you could use android studio, or many other IDEs.